# Error in installation of keras and tensorflow on ubuntu?

Tags: deep-learning

While installing keras and tensorflow on ubuntu using pip, I got an [error exception traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k20oZ.png). How to fix it ?

Comment: Please don't paste images of text. It is much more easy to understand the text.

Comment: Try installing in a virtual environment and rather than using `tensorflow-gpu`, try `tfBinaryUrl` provided [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#the_url_of_the_tensorflow_python_package)

Answer (score 0):

Since, you have not mentioned Python version, I am assuming you are using Python 2.X.
For Python 2.X and for GPU support, this should work.

In terminal, type the following 2 lines:

```
 export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.4.1-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl



 pip install --user TF_BINARY_URL
```

If you are not using Python 2.X, get the correct `tfBinaryURL` from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#the_url_of_the_tensorflow_python_package) for your Python version.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Sumit